# ReactJS + javascript: How to parse array into a new array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of the following:

```
var oldArray = [
    {number: '12345', alphabet: 'abcde'},
    {number: '54321', alphabet: 'abcde'},
    {number: '67891', alphabet: 'abcde'},
    {number: '19876', alphabet: 'abcde'},
]
```

And I would like to extract only the `number` from the `oldArray` and create a new array of them called `newNumberArray` with only the strings and not as objects, like so:

```
var newNumberArray = [
    {'12345'},
    {'54321'},
    {'67891'},
    {'19876'},
]
```

How can I go about doing so?

Comment: This would be done quite easily with native JavaScript's [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Loop through the old array and push each `number` to a new array...

Comment: React doesn't provide anything to help you with that. Use the native JavaScript API or a library like lodash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `{'12345'}` is not a valid JavaScript object, as the value is missing its key.

---

Going forward, I'll be assuming you want to achieve a result like the following:

```
["12345", "54321", "67891", "19876"]
```

**The [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is helpful here:**

```js
var oldArray = [
    {number: '12345', alphabet: 'abcde'},
    {number: '54321', alphabet: 'abcde'},
    {number: '67891', alphabet: 'abcde'},
    {number: '19876', alphabet: 'abcde'},
]
  
var newNumberArray = oldArray.map(function(item) {
  return item.number
})
  
console.log(newNumberArray) // ["12345", "54321", "67891", "19876"]
```

Comment: Thank you really helped!

Answer (score 1):

That's a perfect job for .map ;)

```
var newNumberArray = oldArray.map(function(item){
    return item.number;
});
```

You can see it working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/juanmirod/09yk7a3t/

More about map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map